# Angular $resource array data error

Tags: angularjs

Server response an array data in JSON format:

```
["2345","1234"]
```

Angular service module define:

```
angular.module('MySource', ['ngResource']).factory('Phone', function($resource){
  return $resource('/api/source');
});
```

Then I use `Phone.query();` to fetch array data, but got this:

```
[{"0":"2","1":"3","2":"4","3":"5"},{"0":"1","1":"2","2":"3","3":"4"}]
```

But `$http` works:

```
$http.get('/inner/source').success(function(data){
  // data = ["2345", "1234"]
});
```

What's the problem? Why `$resource` split the array? Does I use `$resource` wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in 1.3.0-beta.12 (see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6314)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$resource` requires the response to be objects, or array of objects. Either change your response to something like this:

```
[{"value":"2345"},{"value":"1234"}]
```

or use the `$http` service